# Does a Full Attack against Sanctuary require one save or multiple?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, attack

The spell [Sanctuary](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sanctuary/) says

> Any opponent attempting to directly attack the warded creature, even with a targeted spell, must attempt a Will save.

Is a Full Attack one attack for the purpose of this spell, or does the attacker need to roll a Will save for every iterative attack?

Comment: Are there any special abilities that the attacker possesses that *could* allow this to happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### You only roll one save.

From the [PFSRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sanctuary/) (*emphasis mine*):

> Any opponent attempting to directly attack the warded creature, even with a targeted spell, must attempt a Will save. If the save succeeds, the opponent can attack normally and is unaffected by *that casting of the spell*. If the save fails, the opponent can’t follow through with the attack, that part of its action is lost, and it can’t directly attack the warded creature *for the duration of the spell*.

A full attack is a type of [full round action](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Full-Round-Actions), rather than an attack in and of itself. When you make the **first** iterative attack against a creature protected by *Sanctuary*, you roll a Will saving throw.

If your saving throw **succeeds**, then you can ignore that casting of *Sanctuary* for the rest of its duration. If the target has *Sanctuary* cast on it again you would need to make the save again, but otherwise you no longer need to make saves against *Sanctuary* to attack the target.

If your saving throw **fails**, then you lose *that* iterative attack and are unable to attack the target until *Sanctuary* ends. If you have 3 attacks in a full attack action, you attack a target protected by *Sanctuary* with the first attack, and you fail your saving throw, then that first attack is lost (you don't even make an attack roll). You can still make your 2 remaining iterative attacks, but they *cannot* target the creature protected by *Sanctuary*.

TLDR: The first time you try to attack a creature protected by *Sanctuary* you make **one** saving throw; if it succeeds you ignore that *Sanctuary* spell; if it fails, you lose the attack and cannot attack that creature until *Sanctuary* ends.